# Line Chart Js x-axis values all 0 on React

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm trying to implement a line graph through chart js on react, however, whenever my function sets the x and y axis data, it keeps returning a line chart that is vertical with x-axis values at 0.

Here is my code below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './LineGraph.css'
import {Line} from "react-chartjs-2"

function LineGraph() {

    const [ graphData, setGraphData ] = useState([])
    const data = [{x:10, y:20}, {x:15, y:10}, {x:12, y:4}]

    const createMockData = () => {
        let data = [];
        let value = 50;
        for(var i = 1; i < 366; i++) {
            let date = new Date()
            date.setHours(0,0,0,0)
            date.setDate(i)
            value += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : 0) * Math.random() * 10)
            data.push({x: value, y:value})
            console.log(data)
        }
        setGraphData(data) 
    }
        
    useEffect(()=> {
        createMockData()
    }, [])
 
    return (
        <div className="linegraph">
            <Line 
                data={{

                    datasets: [
                        {
                            type: "line",
                            data: graphData,
                            backgroundColor: "black",
                            borderColor: "#5AC53B",
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(22, 22, 22, 0)',
                            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
                            pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#5AC53B',
                            pointHoverBorderColor: '#000000',
                            pointHoverBorderWidth: 4,
                            pointHoverRadius: 6,
                        }
                    ]
                }}

                options={{
                    
                    plugins:{
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            interaction: {
                                mode: "index",
                                intersect: false    
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    scales: {
                        x: [
                            {
                                type: "time",
                                time: {
                                    format: "MM/DD/YY",
                                    tooltipFormat: "ll",
                                },
                                ticks: {
                                    display: false,
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                        y: {
                            ticks: {
                                display: false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                     
                }}   
            />
        </div>
    )
}
 
export default LineGraph
```

I'm using react-charts-2, latest version 3.5.1. I think the main problem is with my x-axis because my y-coordinates all show up, which is why the line is vertical, however, all the x values are 0, so their is not diagonal or correlated uphill/downhill line. Please help me resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the x axis scale as an array , this is v2 syntax. All scales have to be defined as an object. So at the moment chart.js sees your scale as a category scale instead of a time scale and it cant handle number inputs as labels.

To fix this you will need to change your scale like so:

```js
scales: {
  x: {
    type: "time",
    time: {
      format: "MM/DD/YY",
      tooltipFormat: "ll",
    },
    ticks: {
      display: false,
    }
  },
  ,
}
```

For using the timescale you will also need a date adapter, since you are using js dates you can just use the normal datefns adapter like so:

```sh
npm install date-fns chartjs-adapter-date-fns --save
```

```js
import {Line} from "react-chartjs-2"
import 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns';
```